# Batch File: move/organize files after image conversion

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory, move

I'm working on a batch script for drag and drop function for a folder which contains image files prepared for conversion. And simply I'm looking for a help with merging those two scripts below:

```
cls
@pushd %~dp0
:::::::::::::::::::
@echo off

set exepath="\\output\_REPO\TOOLS\IMAGE_TOOLS\ImageConvert\IMAGECONV_x64.exe"
set rename=-r

for /r %%i in (*.tga) do %exepath% "%%i"

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *_converted.tga') do (
    set "imagefilename=%%~i"
    set "folder=output"
    mkdir "!folder!" 2>nul
    move /y "!imagefilename!" "!folder!" >nul
)
endlocal
:::::::::::::::::::
@popd

pause
```

After image conversion I'd like to move those converted files (*_converted.tga) to a new folder named "output" which is located in the same directory as the non converted files.

files_for_conversion (here are the files before conversion)
|
|
|_output (here I want to move files after conversion)

Script above only evaluates to a point where image files are converted and then it returns "file not found". When I split it into two parts it works like it should. Second script is evaluated from "output" folder and does the job.

```
cls
@pushd %~dp0
:::::::::::::::::::
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *_converted.tga') do (
    set "imagefilename=%%~i"
    set "folder=output"
    mkdir "!folder!" 2>nul
    move /y "!imagefilename!" "!folder!" >nul
)
endlocal
:::::::::::::::::::
@popd

pause
```

So It'll be nice to have it done in an one step solution rather than two steps.

I'm trying to wrap my head around it but apparently batch commands are not my thing. Any help and advice appreciate it.

Comment: You should store the converted file directly where you want it, either by specifying a parameter to the (unknown) `\IMAGECONV_x64.exe` or by Pushd to the source file location, so you act relative to it's location.

Comment: I've also noticed that when I'm dragging and dropping single files onto *.bat it works actually. I've replaced this line:

FOR /R %%I IN (*.exr) DO %EXEPATH% "%%I"

with

FOR %%I IN (%*) DO %EXEPATH% "%%I"

and it saves the files in a proper folder - about your advice I'd like to see a small example, cause it's like I've wrote batch scripting is above my academical experience :)

Answer (score 0):

Provided the `*_converted.tga` files are stored in the current folder this might do:

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\04\13\SO_49813044.cmd
@echo off

set exepath="\\output\_REPO\TOOLS\IMAGE_TOOLS\ImageConvert\IMAGECONV_x64.exe"
set rename=-r

for /r "%~dp0" %%i in (*.tga) do (
  mkdir "%%~dpi\output" 2>nul
  pushd "%%~dpi\output"
  %exepath% "%%~i"
  popd
)
endlocal
pause
```